# Why doesn't set-header work when requesting express static file url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-security-policy

I am checking web vulnerabilities with 'ZAP'.
And I set up static files in express.

```js
var express = require('express');
const options = { etag: false, setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
    res.set('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 192.168.135.31:10444; form-action 'self'")
  } };
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), options));
```

When I make a 'GET' request to "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static/", the header values set in express and index.html are returned normally.

However, if you request "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static", the header value is not set.

**The difference is the '/' at the end of the URL.**

What is the difference between "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static/" and "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static"?

And how can I receive the header value set when requesting "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static"?

I tried using a helmet,

```js
app.use(helmet({
    frameguard: {
        action: 'deny'
    },
    xssFilter: {
        setOnOldIE: true
    },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'none'"],
            //workerSrc: ["'self'", "192.168.135.31"],
            workerSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "blob:"],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", "data:"],
            formAction: ["'self'"],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "192.168.135.31:10444"],
            frameAncestors: ["192.168.135.31:10444"],
            //scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-eval'"]
            //baseUri: ["/", "http:"]
        }
    }
}));
```

and I tried setting header myself.

```js
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  setHeaders: function(res, path) {
    res.set('Content-Security-Policy', `frame-ancestors 192.168.135.31:10444; form-action 'self'`)
  }
}))
```

However, when making a GET request to "https://192.168.135.31:10444/static"

"Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'" comes in.